# injecting enum(Spring)

Tags: java, spring

I have an `enum`  and I need to inject it with spring bean.

my enum is:

```
public enum Status {


IN_PROCESS(1,"In process"),
DONE(0,"Successful"), 
CANNOT_DONE(2,"Unsuccessful");

private final int code;
private final String description;

private Status(int code, String description){
    this.code = code;
    this.description = description;
}

public int getCode() {
    return code;
}


public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

}
```

what my `bean.xml` should look like for this `enum`..

thanks.

Comment: I tried this one:

<bean id="statusBean" class="entity.Status">
         <constructor-arg value="DONE"></constructor-arg>
        
 </bean>

and got this error:

Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [int]: Ambiguous constructor argument types

Comment: It seems you bean constructor takes an int as argument, and not a Status. Or that it takes two arguments and not just one. Fix that. And show us the code of the bean.

Comment: What is a sense to inject enum?

Answer (score 1):

You can not create an Enum via its constructor from outside of this Enum (not in java and not in Spring) because Enum values are constants!

An Enum constructor can only be invoked from the Enum declarion itselve.

Of course you can use an instance of this Enum, even in Spring, but you can not create it:

```
public Class Entity {    
    public Entity(Status status) {...}
}

<bean name="entity" class="package.Entity">
   <property name="status" value="IN_PROCESS" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically you may try to register enum as a bean like this:

```
@Configuration
class EnumProducer {
   @Bean
   Status inProgress() {
        return Status.IN_PROGRESS;
   }
}
```

and then inject it like:

```
@Autowired("inProgress") Status status.
```

But **there is no any sense** for doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Check `<util:constant/>` here:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/xsd-config.html